# Como pegar valores de um for loop em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

O sistema de notas escolares que estou tentando fazer consiste no seguinte:

São 4 bimestres, o programa lê as notas do aluno em cada bimestre e mostra a média no final de cada repetição do `for` *loop* e mostra na tela.

Quando acabar o `for` ele tem que calcular a média total dos 4 bimestres e mostrar se o aluno está aprovado ou reprovado.

Eu fiz a média de cada bimestre mas não consigo calcular a média total e mostrar se foi ou não aprovado.

O código:

```
print('Sistema de nota escolar')
nome = input ('Qual seu nome: ')




for bimestre in range (1,5):
  print(f'{bimestre} bimestre')
  nota1 = float (input ('Qual sua primeira nota: '))
  nota2 = float (input ('Qual sua segunda nota: '))
  nota3 = float (input ('Qual sua terceira nota: '))
  nota4 = float (input ('Qual sua quarta nota: '))
  media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3 + nota4) / 4
  print (f'Olá {nome} sua Média no {bimestre} bimestre é {media}')
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só acumular as médias (padrão de projeto Accumulator) e dividir no final, como fez com as médias parciais, depois verificar se a nota mínima foi atingida.

```
print('Sistema de nota escolar')
nome = input('Qual seu nome: ')
final = 0
for bimestre in range(1, 5):
    print(f'{bimestre}o. bimestre')
    nota1 = float(input('Primeira nota: '))
    nota2 = float(input('Segunda nota: '))
    nota3 = float(input('Terceira nota: '))
    nota4 = float(input('Quarta nota: '))
    media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3 + nota4) / 4
    final += media
    print(f'Olá {nome} sua média no {bimestre}o. bimestre é {media}')
print(f'Olá {nome} sua média final é {final / 4} e você está {"aprovador" if final / 4 >= 5 else "reprovado"}')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/I5ousc). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/shqejqcutr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/GradeAverage.py).